# Какими знаками препинания выделить слово "наоборот"?

Tags: пунктуация

Папа набивался ей в помощники, уговаривал начать учить, но девочка не соглашалась ни на какую помощь. Вот бы наоборот, настоять на родительской помощи и подсказке.

Answer (score 2):

**Непонятна обоснованность использования слова "наоборот",** так как нет информации о том, отец отступился от своих намерений.

**В качестве варианта:**

1)  Папа набивался ей в помощники, уговаривал начать учить, но девочка не соглашалась ни на какую помощь. В таком случае надо было бы  настоять на родительской помощи и подсказке.

2) Сначала папа набивался ей в помощники, уговаривал начать учить, но девочка не соглашалась ни на какую помощь, и он перестал ее контролировать. А ему бы надо было  **наоборот** настоЯть на родительской помощи и подсказке.

**НАОБОРОТ.** **I. нареч.** 1. В обратном, противоположном направлении, с обратной, противоположной стороны. Прочитать фразу н. 2. **Совершенно иначе, противоположно тому, что нужно или что ожидается**. Поступить н.

**II. вводн. сл.** **=Напротив.**  Стало не теплее, а, н., холоднее. III. частица. (в начале ответной реплики). Вовсе нет, совсем нет. Вам отказали? - Н., согласились печатать книгу.

Comment: Мне понравился Ваш ответ, но он неполный. Надо бы предложить еще один вариант, в котором слово  "наоборот" оставалось бы. Ведь о нем вопрос.

Comment: Попробую привести еще один вариант.

Answer (score 0):

А чем провинилось слово "наоборот", что его непременно надо выделить?

В Вашем примере *наоборот* не вводное...

Слова, на которые падает особое акцентное ударение, выделяют курсивом, полужирным, разрядкой.